# How to implement CDN in Rails application in Production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn

I have my application in my development server, now  i am planning to implement CDN for all the assets used in the application.

How can i do this with Rails? is there any available gem for doing this or any manual configuration has to be done?

I tried googling this topic but found suggestions mostly for Cloud front Heroku.

**Note :** I am using Ngnix in my server and going to buy CDN from a different Vendor.

Comment: u need to look at what CDN companies provides you. then you can modify your app. otherwise, what are you planning to do?

Comment: actually i am going to use my own cdn..
like cdn.mydomain.com..
how do i configure this in my app?
giving only `config.action_controller.asset_host` is enough?

Comment: well i m not familiar with any CDN that rails provide u. but look at Varnish. Here: http://blog.unixy.net/2010/07/how-to-build-your-own-cdn-using-bind-geoip-nginx-and-varnish/

Comment: and let us know how you will do it.

Comment: yes, setting the asset_host will serve your assets from the cdn that you configure. you need to put the data there too. this depends on how you deploy your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution

**Steps to implement custom cdn url**

1) Set the asset path in `config/environment/production.rb`

> config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.mydomain.com"

2) Rename all the styles and js files as shown below
   (if you miss this step, the asset_path tag mentioned in step 3 will not work)

```
assets/stylesheets/styles.css => assets/stylesheets/styles.css.erb
```

3) Update the stylesheet code as shown below

```
background: url(<%= asset_path "sprite/top-tile.png" %>) repeat-x scroll 0 -77px transparent !important;
```

**Note :** But make sure you set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "* or cdn url" in NGINX.
Only then you can access your font family from cdn url as Firefox and IE doesn't allow this by default.

Comment: You can use `image-url('…')` instead of `url(<%= asset_path … %>)` if you'll move to sass/less (they are backward-compatible with plain css, by the way)